# phpmailer error: invalid address

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I am trying to build a mail function with php, but it's justing showing "**Invalid address**:" after execute. Pleas help.

Below is my code:

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object

$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';  
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';   

$mail->From = "myemail@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Web Site";

$mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->addAddress('myfriend@gmail.com');
$mail->AddReplyTo('myfriend@gmail.com');

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
    return false;
} else {
    $error = 'Message sent!';
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You've based your code on an obsolete example, so please make sure you are using latest PHPMailer and base your code on the gmail example provided. You've set `SMTPDebug = 2` but have not shown the output that generates.

Answer (score 3):

Try This

Please write the below line.

```
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8"; // To support special characters in SMTP mail 

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; Comment this line of code
```

I hope this will help you. Good Luck